# D3 - Identifying element by data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm learning D3, and so far I have a basic app that shows a US map and as the user mouses over a state it adds text. What I want to do is also have the state turn to a different color when moused over. What I have so far:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

d3.json("/HelloWorld/data/states.json", function(data) {
  var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa().translate([250,250]).scale(650);
  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("d",path)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("stroke", "blue")
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {

  d3.select("body").append("text").html("</br>"+d.properties.NAME);
});
```

The problem is although I can refer to the data with `d`, I need to be able to refer to the path object in order to change the fill attribute, and I'm not sure how to get from the data to the actual SVG element.

Comment: check this : http://bl.ocks.org/michellechandra/0b2ce4923dc9b5809922

Comment: The `this` keyword refers to the data element being moused over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` keyword refers to the data element being moused over.  From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_on):

> When a specified event is dispatched on a selected node, the specified
>   listener will be evaluated for each selected element, being passed the
>   current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group
>   (nodes), **with this as the current DOM element**. Listeners always see
>   the latest datum for their element, but the index is a property of the
>   selection and is fixed when the listener is assigned; to update the
>   index, re-assign the listener. To access the current event within a
>   listener, use d3.event.

So, just do:

```
.on("mouseover",function(d,i){
    d3.select("body")
      .append("text")
      .html("</br>"+d.properties.NAME);
    d3.select(this)
      .style("fill", someAwesomeColor);
});
```

---

To get the "next" element from the one you mouseover do:

```
.on("mouseover",function(d,i){
    d3.select(originalSelection.nodes()[i + 1])
      .style("fill", someAwesomeColor);
});
```

Where `originalSelection` is the initial selection you call `.data` on.  **Note**, `.nodes` is only available in `d3` version 4.

Comment: Awesome, I had actually tried something like

    this.attr(stuff)

but I guess I needed the d3.select around it. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Although actually I do have one follow-up question. Is it possible to get from data to the element? So for example say each state had an index, and when it was moused over I wanted to change the color of the state with index+1 (for whatever reason), how would I do this? Getting from the element to the data seems easy in d3 but the opposite seems challenging.

Comment: I'm getting the error "ReferenceError: originalSelection is not defined" when I try to use originalSelection.

Comment: @zachvac, originalSelection is a variable returned from your .data call.  You need to define it.

Comment: ok sorry let me try this another way. Say instead of whatever they select I want the user to enter the name of a state, and do something (say change color) to that state. Or as an example say I just want to change the state of "Texas" by hardcoding that string. How can I select the element which is bound to the data which has properties.NAME of that text?

Comment: @zachvac, here's [one implementation](http://plnkr.co/edit/j3I82zPPfkZevg14j4Hn?p=preview).